# Add Image VSCode Minimap

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How I can add image at the Visual Studio Code Minimap ? I see this in a video. I can't find it anywhere, but I have been looking for about an hour. Can anyone help me for this "problem" ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: without evidence of the video I don't believe it is possible

Answer (score 0):

The minimap is a small re-render of the actual editor content, without any view zone. It's not possible to add any other content to it.